# Could not connect to the endpoint aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unix

Trying to use the Amazon Comprehend getting the error:
**botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://comprehend.region.amazonaws.com/"**

I tried searching for a solution on google and stuckoverflow didn't found one that worked for me..

tried setting the Default region name  to [us-east-1] , and more that i find working for other people didn't work for me

```
comprehend = boto3.client(service_name='comprehend', region_name='region')
json.dumps(comprehend.detect_dominant_language(Text=t), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: Why have you set region_name='region'? There is no AWS region named 'region'. You should set this to a real region name such as: region_name='us-east-1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the region must be one of AWS' region code name, such as  'us-east-1' for Northern Virginia, 'eu-west-1' for Ireland etc ...

List of region is available here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

So your code should be

```py
comprehend = boto3.client(service_name='comprehend', region_name='us-east-1')
json.dumps(comprehend.detect_dominant_language(Text=t), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: Oh didn't notice . Thanks for the help!

Comment: you're welcome.  If this works for you, do not forget to tag the answer as correct :-)  Thank you very much